# MvvmCross upgrade from 6.4.2 to 8.0.1

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I recently upgraded MvvmCross from 6.4.2 to 8.0.1 version.
Both Xamarin.Android and Core projects have same nuget packages versions.

After upgrading in ViewModel in line: `IMvxMessenger mvxMessenger = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();` 
I get an error `Failed to resolve type MvvmCross.Plugin.Messenger.IMvxMessenger`

Has anyone already faced such a problem?

Comment: Have you updated Messenger plugin to 8.0.1 as well? Are you trying to resolve that before Setup runs?

Comment: @fmaccaroni yes, I updatet Messenger plugin too. No, I resolve that after Setup runs

Comment: does `Mvx.IoCProvider.CanResolve<IMvxMessenger>();` return false?

Comment: If I were you I'd override `LoadPlugins` on your Setup and do the same code as in Mvx framework https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/8.0.1/MvvmCross/Core/MvxSetup.cs#L397 and check whether the Messenger plugin gets loaded there

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the 6.4.2 version but u can try to add this on initialize/setup

```
Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton<IMvxMessenger>(() => new MvxMessengerHub());
```

This works on the 7.1.2 version

Answer (score 0):

It is related to this issue documented on GitHub.
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/4286

[onurhazar](https://github.com/onurhazar) commented on Oct 8:

> We are having the same issue when we try to load MvxMessenger plugin.
> It throws an exception at app launch (device only)(iOS). As a
> workaround, you can override LoadPlugins method in Setup.cs like
> below;

```
public override void LoadPlugins(IMvxPluginManager pluginManager)
{
      base.LoadPlugins(pluginManager);

      pluginManager.EnsurePluginLoaded<MvvmCross.Plugin.Messenger.Plugin>();
}
```